# How to resolve the error: ITEM expected input to be a number but got the string "12" instead in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list that I'd like to strip out the spaces and square brackets and turn into a number to use elsewhere in the code.

```
turtle-profiles-habitat[ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] ]...

turtle-profiles-habitat-code [ 1 2 3 4 5 12 13 14 15 23 ]...
```

However, the following error appears: ITEM expected input to be a number but got the string "12" instead.

Can I do a string to number transformation?

Thanks in advance

The code below

```
globals [ ValidHabs ]
turtles-own [ turtle-profiles-habitat-code turtle-profiles-habitat t-p-h-item-ValidHabs my-patches ]
patches-own [ habitatcover ]

to setup
  ca
  set ValidHabs [[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 3 4 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 2 3 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]
  (
    foreach ValidHabs [
      this-profile ->
      ask one-of patches [
        sprout 1
        [
          set turtle-profiles-habitat this-profile
          read
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )     
end

to read
  ask turtle who [
    set turtle-profiles-habitat-code reduce_list turtle-profiles-habitat
    print ( word "turtle-profiles-habitat-code is: " turtle-profiles-habitat-code )
  ]

  print ( word "turtle-profiles-habitat-code: " turtle-profiles-habitat-code )
  print ( word "ValidHabs is: " ValidHabs )    
end

to-report reduce_list [a_list]
  report reduce word a_list
end
```

However it is giving the following error:

I made your suggestion and the following error appeared: ITEM expected input to be a number but got the string "12" instead. Is there any way to adjust this? Thanks

Comment: "Can I do a string to number transformation?" yes, you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240742/how-can-i-parse-a-string-in-netlogo is somewhat related. You can use `read-from-string`

Comment: Hi Lena, thank you very much for the reply. I had used read-from-string and it didn't work. I thought string had "" and it doesn't show up. I don't know what I'm wrong about. Could you once again look at the modified code above? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the wanted result for `t-p-h-item-ValidHabs` and what's the difference to `turtle-profiles-habitat`?

Right now, the `turtle-profiles-habitat-code` is not the index of the profile in the `ValidHabs` list, so it is not 12, if it's on the 12th position, but it is "12", when the turtle has the `turtle-profiles-habitat` [1 2].

Comment: Hi Lena, some of your questions I tried to answer above. I edited the question and adjusted the code to make my question clearer and what I want to do with the t-p-h-item-ValidHabs variable. I hope it was less confusing. Sorry for the difficulty in expressing myself! And thanks for the great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a huge workaround, but it works:

`report reduce word a_list` only reports a string, if `a_list` is a list with at least to entries. If it is for example [1], it would only report a number (I didn't know this before)

That's why I make sure that a string is created  with `word reduce word a_list ""`

That string is then reported as a number with `read-from-string`

```
to-report reduce_list [a_list]
  report read-from-string word reduce word a_list ""
end
```

Comment: Lena, thank you very much :) Problem solved